# mysql function type cast error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have function return employee number integer

```
CREATE  FUNCTION `getUser`(s CHAR(20)) RETURNS char(50) CHARSET latin1
RETURN  @user;
```

when i execute its return with (0.00 sec)

but its execute this

```
select e.emp_number from hs_hr_employee e where 

hie_code_1 in ( select hie_code_1 from hs_hr_emp_level L,hs_hr_users U   where L.emp_number=U.emp_number and L.emp_number=getUser2() and  ( U.def_level=1 or U.def_level=4 )   )
or
 hie_code_3 in ( select hie_code_3 from hs_hr_emp_level L,hs_hr_users U   where L.emp_number=U.emp_number and L.emp_number=getUser2()  and  U.def_level=2   )
or
  hie_code_4 in ( select hie_code_4 from hs_hr_emp_level L,hs_hr_users U   where L.emp_number=U.emp_number and L.emp_number=getUser2()   and  U.def_level=3 )
```

get more slower;

but when i hard coded to

```
select e.emp_number from hs_hr_employee e where 

hie_code_1 in ( select hie_code_1 from hs_hr_emp_level L,hs_hr_users U   where L.emp_number=U.emp_number and L.emp_number=5 and  ( U.def_level=1 or U.def_level=4 )   )
or
 hie_code_3 in ( select hie_code_3 from hs_hr_emp_level L,hs_hr_users U   where L.emp_number=U.emp_number and L.emp_number=5  and  U.def_level=2   )
or
  hie_code_4 in ( select hie_code_4 from hs_hr_emp_level L,hs_hr_users U   where L.emp_number=U.emp_number and L.emp_number=5   and  U.def_level=3 )
```

this will return with with (0.00 sec) time.
please give solution for optimiste function ;

Comment: You call getuser2() in your queries, but show a defnition for getUser? What is in the @user var it's returning?

Comment: do you have indexes set up on emp_number and def_level columns?

Comment: Also where does `hie_code_4` come from?

Comment: Simon at mso.net -> getUser2() is a function which will return the parameter value of @user value.

Comment: Joshua Burns -> yes it is there in my table structure.

Comment: Jayanath, what's wrong with just using @user directly?

Comment: Simon at mso.net-> Level hs_hr_emp_level;

Comment: Simon at mso.net -> cant use like that in mysql

Comment: Have you tried it?  You certainly can use it like that, i.e. `SET @foo = 'LGW'; SELECT * FROM airportReference WHERE airportCode = @foo;` (used on one of my local tables

Answer (score 1):

Your samples make my eyes hurt, but here's an attempt at a possible alternative

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.emp_number 

FROM hs_hr_employee e 

INNER JOIN hs_hr_emp_level L
ON L.emp_number = e.emp_number
AND (
    e.hie_code_1 = U.hie_code_1
    OR e.hie_code_3 = U.hie_code_3
    OR e.hie_code_4 = U.hie_code_4
)

INNER JOIN hs_hr_users U 
ON U.emp_number = e.emp_number
AND U.def_level IN (1,2,3,4)

-- You stated getUser2() returns paramter @user, so just accessing directly
WHERE e.emp_number = @user
```

Assumptions as follows

1. `hs_hr_employee.emp_number` == `hs_hr_emp_level.emp_number` == `hs_hr_emp_level.emp_number`
2. `hs_hr_employee.hie_code_*n* ==`hs_hr_users.hie_code_*n*
3. `getUser2()` returns @user, which is an employee number

Syntatically the above does what your complex query is doing.  It's hard to advise as the above feels incorrect - if you won't supply a full table structure / suitable details though then I can't help further.